# Create Dialog without activity

Tags: android, dialog

How can I implement such a dialog, no activity is running.
 Is the activity invisible or what?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I implement such a dialog, no activity is running.

You can't.

> Is the activity invisible or what?

Possibly, perhaps using `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`.

More likely, what you think is a `Dialog` is really a dialog-themed `Activity`. The main themes (e.g., `Theme.Material`, `Theme.AppCompat`) have specific themes with `Dialog` in their names that cause the activity's window to not fill the entire screen.

Comment: Why cant I implement such a thing?

Comment: According to you there is an invisible activity behind this dialog?

Comment: @GautamJain: "According to you there is an invisible activity behind this dialog?" -- that is one possibility. It is not the most likely answer. The most likely answer is that what you are seeing *is* an activity. Neither approach is very common, as popping up a dialog of any form from the background is very hostile, as you do not know what the user is doing when you take over the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog you need to set type of Window which dialog attached, as follows:

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

Do not forget declaring `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission in your manifest.